# $a_{n}= \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ find the monotony

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$ a_{n}= \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

can somebody show me how to prove if the sequence increases or decreases(monotony) ?i would really appreciate it if you could explain too.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the monotony"?

Comment: to prove whether it increases or it decreases..sorry should have described what i wanted better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the difference of consecutive terms. You have

$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} - \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\,.$$

Compare then

$$n\ln(n+1) - (n+1)\ln(n) = \ln\left((n+1)^n\right) - \ln(n^{n+1})\,.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: i ll find the solution by comparing (n+1)^nwith n^(n+1)?

Comment: As the logarithm is a strictly increasing function, it is enough to compare its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dn}\left(a_n\right)=\frac{1-\ln(n)}{n^2}$$
 Thus your sequence is increasing on $(0,e)$ and decreasing on $(e,\infty)$.